# How to search for library functions in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, suppose I need to find a function whose name contains the word 'tabulate'. How should I search for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like 'find' and 'grep' to do this sort thing if you have already installed ATS.

Say that your installation of ATS is located at ${PATSHOME}. The following command-line searches the word 'tabulate' is SATS-files stored under the `prelude` directory:

```
find ${PATSHOME}/prelude -type f | grep -P '.sats$' | xargs grep -iH tabulate
```

Another place to look for library functions is ${PATSHOME}/libats.

For compiling to targets like JavaScript and Python, please look for library functions in ${PATSCONTRIB}/contrib/libatscc, where ${PATSCONTRIB} is the name of the directory containing your installation of ATS2-contrib.